# Converting Binary to Decimal in python (without built in binary function)

Tags: python, binary

Alrighty, first post here, so please forgive and ignore if the question is not workable;

Background:
I'm in computer science 160.  I haven't taken any computer related classes since high school, so joining this class was a big shift for me. It all seemed very advanced.  We have been working in Python and each week we are prompted to write a program.

I have been working with this problem for over a week and am having a hard time even starting.
The prompt is to read an integer containing only 1's and 0's,
process the binary number digit by digit and report the decimal equivalent.  Now, I have gotten some tips from a classmate and it sent me at least in a direction.

Set up a couple of counters;
using the `%` operator to check the remainder of the number divided by 2, and slicing off the last number (to the right) to move on to and process the next digit.

I am having an incredibly hard time wrapping my head around what formula to use on the binary digits themselves which will convert the number to decimal.

```
setbitval = 0
counter = 0

user = int(input("enter a binary value. "))

if user % 2 == 1:
        user = (user/10) - .1
        setbitval += 1
```

This is all I've got so far.. My thinking is getting in the way.  I've searched and searched, even through these forums.

Any information or thoughts are extremely appreciated,
T

Edit: okay guys, everyone's help has been extremely useful but I'm having a problem checking if the user input is not a binary number.

```
for i in reversed(bits):   
decimal += 2**counter * int(i)

counter += 1
```

This is the formula someone here gave me and I've been trying different iterations of "for i in bits:  if i in bits: != 0 or 1" and also "if i in bits: >= 1 or <=0".
Any thoughts?

Comment: So you aren't allowed to just do `DecValue= int(input("enter a binary value. "), 2)`?

Comment: Or something like stringifying the integer, reversing it, and iterating over it, adding increasing powers of two as you progress through the string.

Comment: @NendoTaka What I'm interpreting from that code is that the user input is going to be in base 2? What would this achieve? 
Thank you for the comment.

Sam van, This concept does remind me of some of the stuff I found in the forums.  But addressing each digit and manipulating them individually is still a mystery to me.

Thank you both; it feels like I'm getting into the "code this for me" territory.  I've basically had to teach the basics to myself.. Thank you again

Comment: @SamvanKampen   sorry, trying to refer to you as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To convert binary value to decimal you need to do the following:

Take the least significant bit and multiply it by 2^0, then take the next least significant beat and multiply it by 2^1, next one by 2^2 and so on...

Let's say, for example you need to convert a number 1010 to decimal:

You would have 0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^3 = 0 + 2 + 0 + 8 = 10

So in your python code, you need to:

- read the int that the user inputted (representing the binary value).
- convert that int and convert it to string, so you can break it into list of digits
- make a list of digits from the string you created (a list int python can be created from a string not an int, that's why you need the conversion to string first)
- go trough that list of bits in reverse and multiply every bit by 2^k, k being the counter starting from 0

Here's the code that demonstrates what I just tried to explain:

```
user_input = int(input("enter a binary value"))

bits = list(str(user_input))

decimal = 0

counter = 0

for i in reversed(bits):
    decimal += 2**counter * int(i)
    counter+=1

print 'The decimal value is: ', decimal
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for comment.  I had to change the raw_input to just input for my version of python.  Reverse the bits so we can manipulate them in an easier fashion?  Then the loop adds "(2 to the power of counter times the user's binary value)"?

Comment: When you're converting from binary to decimal the formula is 2^0*bit_val(0 or 1) + 2^1*bit_val + 2^2*bit_val...where you take the last bit first, then the next one from right to left until you get to the first bit. That's why you need to reverse the bits. So, you take the user input, make a list of bits from it, then reverse the list and apply the above formula....The last bit represents the 0 or 1 in decimal, the nest bit from right to left represents 2 or 0 in decimal, the next one 4 or 0, the next one 8 or 0 etc. When you add all those values you get the decimal representation of the value

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the methodology. I don’t feel quite as left out in the wild as i did. It sounds like making a list separates the bits so they can be individually manipulated.

Comment: That's the idea. I'm glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
binary= raw_input("Binary: ")
d= int(binary, 2)
print d
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I can conceptualize your code at this point, but I also don’t think my instructor would accept just the three lines. I think i have an idea how to put it all together after chatting here, but I’ve got to explain the method and use a more expanded formula. Your code is saying “Store user’s string, and then convert that string into an integer in base 2?

Comment: yup, you introduce a string of binary digits and it converts to decimal, you can add a loop if you need to convert more than one

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree this is close to the "code this for me" territory, but I'll try to answer in a way that gets you on the right track, instead of just posting a working code snippet.

A simple way of doing this is just to use `int()`'s base argument, but I'm guessing that is disallowed.

You already have a way of testing the current bit in your question, namely checking whether `n % 2 == 1`. If this is the case, we need to add a power of two.

Then, we need some way of going to the next bit. In binary, we would use bit shifts, but sadly, we don't have those. `a >> b` is equivalent to `a // (2**b)` - can you write a decimal equivalent to that?

You also need to keep a counter of which power of two the current bit represents, a loop, and some way of detecting an end condition. Those are left as exercises to the reader.

Comment: Thanks Sam; that formula would take the user's binary value, divide it by "(2 to the power of B)", correct?
And B is going to be a counter of some sort I'll set up?  Namely which bit I'm referring and which power of two to use?

Comment: When a bit tests positive (e.g. `n % 2 == 1`), you want to add the right power of two to the decimal value. This means you'll have to keep track of the current power of two in some variable.

Thereafter, you want to go on to the next bit (e.g. `1001` should become `100`). To do that, you need to do something akin to a [bit shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift), but in decimal.

Comment: Thank you Kampen. It looks like there is no operator for bit shifting in python, so figuring out some way to emulate that would be necessary. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend reading the following articles on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

The first one gives you an idea how the numeral systems work in general and the second one explains and shows the formula to convert between binary and decimal systems.
Try to implement the solution after reading this. That’s what I did when I dealt with this problem. If that doesn’t help, let me know and I’ll post the code.

Hopefully, this code clarifies things a bit.

```
x = input("Enter binary number: ").strip()
decimal = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    decimal += int(x[i]) * 2**abs((i - (len(x) - 1)))
print(decimal)
```

This code takes in a binary number as a string, converts it to a decimal number and outputs it as an integer. The procedure is the following:

1st element of binary number * 2^(length of binary number - 1)

2nd element of binary number * 2^(length of binary number - 2)

and so on till we get to the last element and ...2^0

If we take number 10011, the conversion using this formula will look like this:
1*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0, which equals to 19.

This code, however, assumes that the binary number is valid. Let me know if it helps.

Another implementation using while loop might look like this. Maybe it'll be easier to understand than the code with the for loop.

```
x = input("Enter binary number: ").strip()
decimal = 0
index = 0
exp = len(x) - 1
while index != len(x):
    decimal += int(x[index]) * 2**exp
    index += 1
    exp -= 1
print(decimal)
```

In this one we start from the beginning of the number with the highest power, which is *length of binary number minus one*, we loop through the number, lowering the power and changing index.

Regarding checking if number is binary.
Try using helper function to determine if number is binary and then insert this function inside your main function. For example:

```
def is_binary(x):
    """ Returns True if number x is binary and False otherwise.

    input: x as a string
    """
    for i in list(x):
        if i not in ["1", "0"]:
            return False
    return True


def binary_decimal(x):
    """ Converts binary to decimal.
    input: binary number x as a string
    output: decimal number as int
    """
    if not is_binary(x):
        return "Number is invalid"
    decimal = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        decimal += int(x[i]) * 2**abs((i - (len(x) - 1)))
    return decimal
```

The first function checks if number consists only of ones and zeros and the second function actually converts your number only if it's binary according to the first function.
You can also try using assert statement or try / except if you'd better raise an error if number is not binary instead of simply printing the message.

Of course, you can implement this solution without any functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and link.  If you were to post code, it may be clear by now that it probably wouldn't do me much good other than copy and pasting.  Thank you again, and I will read into the wiki page.

Comment: So I did run into the formula for converting to decimal which i had found before. The other day I got lost in trying to use the “len()” of the user input and emulating the formula for conversion. It was overwhelming.

Comment: I’m having trouble checking whether or not the user input is binary or not. Is there a way to implement that before the formula?

Comment: I've added some code with description. Let me know if it helps.